# Extracting zalgo text from online generator

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I'm familiar with entry-level webscraping in python. Can I somehow run python script that asks for input string, after which zalgo text of provided string is written in some file? I can use [this](https://lingojam.com/CreepyZalgoTextGenerator) generator for example.

Comment: I'll do ya one better (I know this isn't in the spirit of this question, just for fun) - If you dig into the sources of that online generator, you'll find the JS source https://lingojam.com/js/translate.js?v=29786864 , which *seems* to be doing the zalgo translation work. So you could take the translation offline if you wanted (and felt like translating that mess into Python)

Comment: @thisisbenmanley thank you very much i'll try it tomorrow